# PowerShell: FileSystemWatcher not working

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

The code runs with no errors, however when I add/delete a file in the filesystem, the code does not perform the action it should in `Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "watchType" -Action $action`. I know this because in the past, it was working and would create/add to `log.txt` a record of the file deleted/added and its date. Now, nothing happens. What is going on?

Code:

```
#local path of the folder you want to sync. By default sets to current directory
$localPath = get-location

#filter specific files by name/type
$filter = "*.*"


#include subdirectories
$inclSubDirectories = $true


#end of user defined variables

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $localPath
$watcher.Filter = $filter
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $inclSubDirectories
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$oldContent = ""

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "'$localPath'\log.txt" -value $logline
}

$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action

$action1 = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "'$localPath'\log.txt" -value $logline
}

$deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action1

$exitAction = {
    "File wathcer unregistered!"
    Unregister-Event $created
    Unregister-Event $deleted
}

$exit = Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -action $exitAction

while ($true) {
    if($oldContent -eq $logline){}
    else{
        $logline
        $oldContent = $logline
    }
    Start-Sleep -m 1000
}
```

**EDIT**

I decided to try to copy and paste the code directly into PowerShell, and it works the way it should...
Not entirely, it doesn't output but it does update log.txt like how it should.
Actually, it only worked once. Now it's back to what it was like before.

**EDIT v2**

It seems to work only once per event (create, then delete) when I copy-paste into the PowerShell (for instance, it would register a file deleted in log, then it would register a file created, but it wouldn't do anything else.) It is still not outputting like it should.

Comment: I think the `while ($true)` loop totally blocks the main thread in which event callbacks are supposed to run. Why do you need it?

Comment: @wOxxOm I commented out the loop section, and the script would close because it has reached the end of the script. Also, I had a loop there before when it was working, so I dont think thats the issue.

Comment: I still think it's wrong without at least `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100` inside the loop.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added that and it sill didnt work. Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see here for your `$localpath` is having the Current path and the problem comes when you do `Add-Content`.

In below line, The path comes with singelqoutes in it, which is not existing any way.

`Add-content "'$localPath'\log.txt" -value $logline`

See it by just printing `"'$localPath'\log.txt"`.

Correct Expression would be `Add-content "$localPath\log.txt" -value $logline`

As well as on each `Register-ObjectEvent` execution, a job will be created,try

`Receive-Job -Id <Job ID> -keep` to see what is happening/happened.

Regards

kvprasoon

Comment: I used Get-EventSubscriber instead of Receive-Job and saw that all the events were registered, yet it still wasn't working. However, I decided to try to copy and paste the code directly into PowerShell, and it works the way it should...